# Робітник чи працівник?

Tags: вибір-слова

Недавно почула вираз "*науковий робітник*", хоча завжди була впевнена, що робітник — людина, праця якої пов'язана з фізичними зусиллями. Але у [тлумачному словнику](http://sum.in.ua/s/robitnyk) таки знайшла одне з визначень слова *робітник*, як *людина, зайнята в якій-небудь певній галузі. діяльності.* Як тоді бути з *працівником*? Коли доцільно вживати *робітник* та *працівник*?

Answer (score 3):

Працівник, -а. 1. Член якогось виробничого колективу, особа, яка бере участь у певному трудовому процесі, працює за певним фахом, у якійсь галузі народного господарства, науки, культури. Вж. зі сл.: здібний, кваліфікований, керівний, літературний, науковий, торговельний, газети (газетний), заповідника, кіно, преси, сцени (член творчого колективу театру). 2. Трудівник. Наш мужик – то неук темний, Працівник, але бідар(П.Грабовський); Не голоси чаїні – наш одностайний крик: Рівняйтеся пустині! Поборе працівник!(М.Рильський).

Робітник, -а. 1. Той, хто створює матеріальні цінності, працюючи на промисловому підприємстві; людина, що належить до робітничого класу; в давні часи – також наймит: робітники фабрик і заводів, робітники й селяни, кваліфікований робітник, робітники сцени (особи, які встановлюють і міняють декорації тощо). 2.Трудівник. Всі мали його за чесного чоловіка та доброго робітника (М.Коцюбинський); Не жрець, не вождь, а робітник – Поета справжнього імення... (М.Рильський).

[Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53408/32073.html)